# How can I turn 2 strings into a key?

Tags: python

I have 2 strings with alphabetic values (a-e) & numeric values (1-5):

```
 num = 12345
 let = abcde
```

How can I get this using a for loop?

```
[1a, 2b, 3c, 4d, 5e]
```

Comment: Yes this is very possible in a for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there you go:

```
num = '12345'
let = 'abcde'

keys = [n+l for n,l in zip(num, let)]
```

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that let and num are strings

```
>>> num = "12345"
>>> let = "abcde"
```

you could use [zip](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> [''.join(i) for i in zip(num,let)]
['1a', '2b', '3c', '4d', '5e']
```

Comment: OP needs it as `['1a', '2b', '3c', '4d', '5e']` not as `['a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'd4', 'e5']`